# How to use SharedPreferences from differents activities?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have searched how to use SharedPreferences in Android and ran into a problem.

I save some `Strings` in the `SP` and I save the data in `Main Activity` this way:

in `OnCrete` function I define:

```
    sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
```

and then I save the strings to SharedPreferences in the following way:

```
mail = edmail.getText().toString();
            pass = edpass.getText().toString();
            color = edcolor.getText().toString();
            phone = edphone.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            if (mail.equals("") || pass.equals("") || color.equals("") || phone.equals("")||img.getDrawable() == null
                    )
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you have to fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                editor.putString("mail", mail);
                editor.putString("phone", phone);
                editor.putString("color", color);
                editor.putString("password", pass);

                editor.apply();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("img",bitmap);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

In the second activity I am trying to retrieve the data:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("img");
    imgv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    LoadPreferences();

    //txtmail.setText(value);
}
private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String  data = sharedPreferences.getString("mail", null) ;
    Toast.makeText(this,data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The toast presents the default value instead the real value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You saved your data in `MyPref` file which is a different shared preference file as compared to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

so use

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

instead of

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

`getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);` will always creates a new file if does not exist whereas the `getDefaultSharedPreferences` gives you a pref file which is can be used by whole app whit mentioning any name

Comment: Quick add-on: OP should be using `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` instead of just `0`.

Comment: thanks though `0` is the value of mode private so both are same thing though I agree that `Context.MODE_PRIVATE ` is more readable and makes more sense

Comment: It's just the recommended way, so I recommended it :p

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Change your loading declaration:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

To:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Pavneet's answer.